# What exactly determines whether Google Maps shows a "3D mode" button or not?

Tags: google-maps

Lately, I have been loading Google Maps with links from my own map system, always in the same way, always in the same browser, with the same computer, same configuration, same everything.

Randomly, it has hidden the "Enter 3D mode" button, disabling me from looking around in 3D. Then the next time, it might show it, and then the next time, it's gone again.

It appears to have nothing to do with *where* on the world map I'm looking. It also doesn't matter how far in/out I'm zoomed. All areas can enter *some* kind of 3D view, although not all places have fleshed-out 3D objects of every single house/object/tree.

So why does it sometimes not show that button? It's infuriating to say the least.

To make it clear, it's (normally) in the bottom-right, above the "crosshair" button which in turn is above the "+" and "-" buttons for zooming in and out.

Example: https://www.google.com/maps/@59.9129672,10.7560534,616m/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en

No "3D mode button", at least for me, right now. But tomorrow, it'll most likely be there again for me. It comes and goes with seemingly no rhyme or reason.